# Why can't hyperfunctions be coerced in GHC?

Tags: haskell, coercion, profunctor

I have the following type, which is based on the paper [Coroutining folds with hyperfunctions](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1309.5135.pdf):

```hs
newtype Hyper a b = Hyper { invoke :: Hyper b a -> b }
```

It's contravariant in its first argument and covariant in its second, so it's a profunctor:

```hs
instance Profunctor Hyper where
  lmap f = go where
    go (Hyper h) = Hyper $ \(Hyper k) -> h $ Hyper $ f . k . go

  rmap g = go where
    go (Hyper h) = Hyper $ \(Hyper k) -> g $ h $ Hyper $ k . go

  dimap f g = go where
    go (Hyper h) = Hyper $ \(Hyper k) -> g $ h $ Hyper $ f . k . go
```

I also want to implement the (potentially unsafe) coercion operators:

```hs
  -- (#.) :: Coercible c b => q b c -> Hyper a b -> Hyper a c
  (#.) _ = coerce

  -- (.#) :: Coercible b a => Hyper b c -> q a b -> Hyper a c
  (.#) = const . coerce
```

However, when I do so, I get the following error message:

```
   • Reduction stack overflow; size = 201
     When simplifying the following type:
       Coercible (Hyper a b) (Hyper a c)
     Use -freduction-depth=0 to disable this check
     (any upper bound you could choose might fail unpredictably with
      minor updates to GHC, so disabling the check is recommended if
      you're sure that type checking should terminate)
   • In the expression: coerce
     In an equation for ‘#.’: (#.) _ = coerce
```

I guess it's trying to verify `Coercible (Hyper a b) (Hyper a c)`, which requires `Coercible b c` and `Coerrcible (Hyper c a) (Hyper b a)`, and the latter requires `Coercible (Hyper a b) (Hyper a c)`, but it goes in an endless loop.

Any idea what annotations I'd use to fix this, if any? Or should I just bite the bullet and use `unsafeCoerce`?

Comment: Wow, that sure sounds like a GHC bug! Please report it!

Comment: In the mean time, your best/only bet might be to make your instance an orphan. That *might* give you enough control to guide resolution manually, rather than having the wrap/unwrap coercion axioms throw a wrench into the works.

Comment: Hmm... Actually, that's pretty tricky. No, there's probably no workaround.

Comment: I guess you don't want `(#.) _ = rmap coerce`, right?

Comment: @chi, that isn't useful at all because it isn't free.

Comment: @dfeuer I know it's not free, but I would consider that to be "not as useful" instead of "completely useless". Further, in my view, even if `(#.)` was free, having that would still be suboptimal, since I can't derive, say, `... => [Hyper a b] -> [Hyper a' b']` from that alone. The optimal solution would be to have `Coercible (Hyper a b) (Hyper a' b')` (which is of course what the OP would need to make their code work).

Comment: @chi, I should have been more specific. Writing that definition is not useful at all because that's what the default definition does.

Answer (score 1):

I assume it's clear that the `Profunctor` instances play no role here, and so the following self-contained program gives the same error:

```
import Data.Coerce
newtype Hyper a b = Hyper { invoke :: Hyper b a -> b }
(#.) :: (Coercible c b) => q b c -> Hyper a b -> Hyper a c
(#.) _ = coerce
```

I don't think this is a bug; rather, it's a limitation of the algorithm used for inferring type-safe coercions.  In [the paper](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/uploads/prod/2018/05/coercible-JFP.pdf) that describes the algorithm, it's acknowledged that type checking recursive newtypes may diverge, and the "as designed" behavior is that the reduction counter will detect the loop and report an error.  (See page 27 for example.)  It's further noted on page 30 that "indeed, we know that with its treatment of recursive newtypes...the algorithm is incomplete" (i.e., that there are type-safe coercions that cannot be inferred by the algorithm as implemented).  You might also want to browse the discussion in issue [#15928](https://gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/ghc/issues/15928) regarding a similar loop.

What happens here is that GHC tries to solve `Coercible (Hyper a b) (Hyper a c)` by first unwrapping the newtypes to yield the new goal:

```
Coercible (Hyper b a -> b) (Hyper c a -> c)
```

This requires `Coercible (Hyper b a) (Hyper c a)` which GHC tries to solve by first unwrapping the newtypes to yield the new goal:

```
Coercible (Hyper a b -> a) (Hyper a c -> a)
```

which requires `Coercible (Hyper a b) (Hyper a c)`, and we're caught in a loop.

As in the issue #15928 example, this is because of the unwrapping behavior for newtypes.  If you switch the newtype to a `data`, it works fine, since GHC doesn't try to unwrap and instead can derive `Coercible (Hyper a b) (Hyper a c)` directly from `Coercible b c` and the representational role of `Hyper`'s second parameter.

Unfortunately, the whole algorithm is syntax-directed, so newtypes will always be unwrapped this way, and there's no way to get GHC to "hold off" on the unwrapping and try an alternative proof.

Except that there is...  Newtypes are only unwrapped if the constructor is in scope, so you can separate it into two modules:

```
-- HyperFunction.hs
module HyperFunction where
newtype Hyper a b = Hyper { invoke :: Hyper b a -> b }

-- HyperCoerce.hs
module HyperCoerce where
import HyperFunction (Hyper)  -- don't import constructor!
import Data.Coerce
(#.) :: (Coercible c b) => q b c -> Hyper a b -> Hyper a c
(#.) _ = coerce
```

and it type checks fine.

If this is too ugly or causes some other problems, then I guess `unsafeCoerce` is the way to go.

Comment: Oy. I guess my initial guess was better than my later one. What a horrible thing: bringing a constructor into scope prevents a module from typechecking. That frankly seems like an unacceptable situation!

Comment: Does anybody have an explanation for this? Sounds almost like the newtype-unwrapping was only introduced as a hack for something very specific.

Comment: FYI, I just opened a [GHC ticket](https://gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/ghc/issues/18306) to have a look at this.

Comment: @leftaroundabout, `newtype` wrapping/unwrapping is one of the fundamental types of coercion axiom. And it's rather useful: `coerce :: [a] -> [Sum a]` and such.